# Filling <img> in flexbox and retaining aspect ratio without JavaScript

Tags: css, flexbox

Title says it all. I'm looking for a solution to make `img` tag fill parent (image and parent are of unknown size) while respecting aspect ratio, also without using `background-size` or any other workaround. I need the block with the image to have size of that picture (which `background-size` does not). I tried many things, like `min-width` and `min-height`, some strange things with `zoom`, many combinations of `width/height: 100%/auto/0`.

EDIT: I should have stated it in original text. I want to show **whole image**, not just crop a part from it. So correct result will have free space on left&right or top&bottom (this free space is not occupied by said image, only by the container).

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  border: 2px solid darkblue;
  height: 95%;
  width: 97%;
}

#pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/CtHGCLF.jpg?1" id="pic">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this would solve the problem.

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  border: 2px solid darkblue;
  height: 95%;
  width: 97%;
text-align: center;
}

#pic {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/CtHGCLF.jpg?1" id="pic">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. After minor modification (wrapping image inside another div with height&width 100%, probably something with #container being absolutely positioned) it works nicely :).

Answer (score 0):

`height:auto` should do the magic:

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  border: 2px solid darkblue;
  width: 97%;
}

#pic {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: max-content;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/CtHGCLF.jpg?1" id="pic">
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it causes `#container` to overflow http://codepen.io/monnef/pen/oXpZQo (I want the container to have `height: 100%` or arbitrary but not being inflated by `img`). I have edited question to be more specific, sorry.